# Powershell: Update-TfsWorkspace cmdlet how to update two workspaces

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-cmdlet

I want to update 2 workspaces from two different tfs in one script using powershell.
The first Workspace is updating without any Problems. After the update is finished powershell connects to the second Workspace, but isn't updating the local data like the first time.

I guess the old Connection might still block the pipe or something like that, but I haven't found any cmd to clean the pipe. My code looks like this:

```
param(
      [string]$TestTFS = "http://TestTFS",
      [string]$ProdTFS = "http://ProdTFS",
      [string]$Teamproject="$\TeamprojectPath",
      [string]$LocalTestWorkspace="C:\LocalTestWorkspacePath",
      [string]$LocalProdWorkspace="C:\LocalProdWorkspacePath"
     )

# Import Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell Snapin
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell

# Connect to production-TFS
$ProdEnvServer = Get-TfsServer -Name $ProdTFS
Write-Host "tfsConnect ="$ProdEnvServer

# Get prod teamprojekt
Get-TfsChildItem $Teamprojekt -Server $ProdEnvServer

# Update files in local prod workspace
Update-TfsWorkspace -Force -Recurse $LocalProdWorkspace


# Connect to test-TFS
$TestEnvServer = Get-TfsServer -Name $TestTFS
Write-Host "tfsConnect ="$TestEnvServer

# Get test teamprojekt
Get-TfsChildItem $Teamprojekt -Server $TestEnvServer

# Update files in local test workspace
Update-TfsWorkspace -Force -Recurse $LocalTestWorkspace
```

Comment: Where are you running this PS script from?  ie C:\LocalProdWorkspacePath ?

Comment: I'm actually running it from D:\Powershell\Test.ps1

Comment: try cd ing to the second workspace before you do the second get

Comment: Didn't change anything. It's interesting that even if I switch the first and second Connection after running the script once, it's still just updating the Workspace which was updated in the beginning. I even tried to split up the Connection,Get und Update for both workspaces into 2 seperate scripts which I ran from a third script, same Problem. When powershell and the pipe are empty from the start and I run the test Connection before the production, it updating just the test Workspace. So it's definitely not a matter of the Connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 3 months and noone coming up with an answer. I just assume that the Cmdlets don't work as they should. The only option here seems to be a Workaround.

```
# Copy Team Project from Prod to Test TFS

param([string]$TestTFS = "http://TestTFS",
[string]$ProdTFS = "http://ProdTFS",
[String]$Teamproject="$/Teamproject",
[String]$LocalTestWorkspace="C:\LocalTestWorkspacePath",
[String]$LocalProdWorkspace="C:\LocalProdWorkspacePath")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client")

try 
{
clear

$LocalTestProjectPath = $LocalTestWorkspace + $Teamproject.Substring(1)
$LocalProdProjectPath = $LocalProdWorkspace + $Teamproject.Substring(1)

# Connect to production-TFS
Write-Host "Getting latest of $ProdTFS"
$tfsColProd = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($ProdTFS)
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer] $vcsProd = $tfsColProd.GetService([type] "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")

# TryGetWorkspace is sometimes buggy and doesn't return an existing workspace
# Delete existing workspace manually before if that happens
$workspaceProd = $vcsProd.TryGetWorkspace($LocalProdWorkspace)

$isProdTempWorkspace = $false

# create Workspace if it doesn't exists
if (-not $workspaceProd) {
    Write-Host "No workspace found, creating temporary for prod"
    $workspaceProd = $vcsProd.CreateWorkspace("Temp_" + [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())
    $workspaceProd.Map($Teamproject, $LocalProdProjectPath)
    $isProdTempWorkspace = $true
}

$itemSpecFullTeamProj = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemSpec($Teamproject, "Full")
$fileRequest = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetRequest($itemSpecFullTeamProj, 
    [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest)

$workspaceProd.Get($fileRequest, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::GetAll)

if ($isProdTempWorkspace) {
    Write-Host "Deleting temporary workspace for prod"
    $workspaceProd.Delete()
}

Write-Host "Getting latest of $TestTFS"
$tfsColTest = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($TestTFS)
$vcsTest = $tfsColTest.GetService([type] "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")

# TryGetWorkspace is sometimes buggy and doesn't return an existing workspace
# Delete existing workspace manually before if that happens
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace] $workspaceTest = $vcsTest.TryGetWorkspace($LocalTestWorkspace)
$isTestTempWorkspace = $false

# create Workspace if it doesn't exists
if (-not $workspaceTest) {
    Write-Host "No workspace found, creating temporary for test"
    $workspaceTest = $vcsTest.CreateWorkspace("Temp_" + [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())
    $workspaceTest.Map($Teamproject, $LocalTestProjectPath)
    $isTestTempWorkspace = $true
}

$workspaceTest.Get($fileRequest, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::GetAll)

# Remove local test folder and copy prod folder into test workspace
Write-Host "Copying over Prod to Test"

# Delete updated test project folder 
Remove-Item -Path $LocalTestProjectPath -Force -Recurse

# Copy prod folder to test workspace
Copy-Item -Path $LocalProdProjectPath -Destination $LocalTestProjectPath -Force -Recurse

# Calling tfpt is the only thing that works
Write-Host "Comparing for changes"
$ps = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps.StartInfo.Filename = $env:TFSPowerToolDir + "tfpt.exe"
$ps.StartInfo.Arguments = "online /adds /deletes /diff /noprompt /recursive $LocalTestProjectPath"
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $false # careful, only output works, has hanging problems (2k Buffer limit)
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $false 
$ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$ps.Start()
$ps.WaitForExit()

# Check in new test project folder into test environment
$wsCheckinParams = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WorkspaceCheckInParameters(
    @($itemSpecFullTeamProj),"Update project to production environment version")
# CheckIn better manually to check for errors
$workspaceTest.CheckIn($wsCheckinParams)


if ($isTestTempWorkspace) {
   Write-Host "Deleting temporary workspace for test"
   $workspaceTest.Delete()
   Remove-Item -Path D:\Development -Force -Recurse
}
}

catch [System.Exception]
{
   Write-Host "Exception: " ($Error[0]).Exception 
   EXIT $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is very similar to Zittelrittel. Just send the path and it will automatically figure out the workspace.

***This will not work in PowerShell ISE (x86), I had to use the 64-bit version!***

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell

Write-Host "Updating Workspace1, please wait..."
Update-TfsWorkspace -item C:\dev\Workspace1\code -Recurse | Format-Table

Write-Host "Updating Workspace2, please wait..."
Update-TfsWorkspace -item C:\dev\Workspace1\code -Recurse | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calls to update TFS workspace, pipe the result to out-null. This should effectively remove any data that would otherwise be stored in the pipeline.

```
Update-TfsWorkspace -Force -Recurse $LocalProdWorkspace | Out-Null
Update-TfsWorkspace -Force -Recurse $LocalTestWorkspace | Out-Null
```